# FullCalender : calender.render() makes browser window unresponsive

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

**Update: I've narrowed down the issue to dayGrid plugin. Don't know why this is still happening.
The browser window is now not freezing, but I'm receiving the below error:
Downgrading the source to version 5.3.0 worked**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isHiddenDay' of undefined
    at new DaySeriesModel (main.cjs.js:8089)
    at DayTableView.buildDayTableModel (main.cjs.js:887)
    at DayTableView.buildDayTableModel (main.cjs.js:975)
    at DayTableView../node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.cjs.js.DayTableView.render (main.cjs.js:877)
    at $ (preact.js:1)
    at x (preact.js:1)
    at I (preact.js:1)
    at $ (preact.js:1)
    at x (preact.js:1)
    at $ (preact.js:1)
```

The above error seems to be a bug within the source for FullCalendar 5.7.

I'm not sure exactly what's going on, `calendar.render()` stops the page from loading and it just hangs.

Anyone experience this before, is it an issue with the order imports are happening?

calendar.js

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar')

  const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
    },
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    events: 'https://127.0.0.1/wp-json/api/v1/events'
  })

  calendar.render()
})
```

main.js

```
import './scripts/publicPath'
import 'console-polyfill'
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css'
import './main.scss'
import $ from 'jquery'
import feather from 'feather-icons'

import installCE from 'document-register-element/pony'

import '../node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/cjs/popper'
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle'
import '../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize'
import '../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min'
import '../node_modules/aos/dist/aos'
import '../node_modules/jquery-mask-plugin/dist/jquery.mask'
import '../node_modules/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup'
import '../node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select'
import './scripts/init'
import './scripts/filtering'
import './scripts/aos'
import './scripts/customSlick'
import './scripts/setHeight'
import './scripts/setWaves'
import './scripts/masks'
import './scripts/lightBox'
import './scripts/calendar'

window.jQuery = $

window.lazySizesConfig = window.lazySizesConfig || {}
window.lazySizesConfig.preloadAfterLoad = true
require('lazysizes')

$(document).ready(function () {
  feather.replace({
    'stroke-width': 1
  })
})

installCE(window, {
  type: 'force',
  noBuiltIn: true
})

function importAll (r) {
  r.keys().forEach(r)
}

importAll(require.context('../Components/', true, /\/script\.js$/))
```

Comment: Check spelling: `import intertaction from '@fullcalendar/interaction'` should be `interaction`

Comment: Hey mankowitz, thanks for the tip, I've switched it over but it's still freezing. Looks like it was misspelled in two areas but still being called.

Comment: I was facing a similar issue (browser freeze) and it was caused by not including the CSS file. Is the `fullcalendar` CSS being included?